# Where to put unit tests helper source files in my directory structure

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, architecture, directory-structure

I have the following directory structure in a javascript project

```
/src
/test
```

The test directory is an image of src directory, where each file of the first has a related test file in the second. However I have some common helper source files that are used by the files under test directory in order to perform testing.

Where should I put them? under test or src dir, or should I create another dir? I know it might be a matter of preference, just asking for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a matter of preference.

Why do you have /src helper code in /test? Are the /src helper methods/functions tightly binded to other /test methods/functions or loosely coupled? If it's the latter, personally I would move them out of /test and place them under /src/helpers or something similar.

Over time you might integrate the helper code into the code files in /src and/or create more helper methods to help you with writing code in /src, and when writing your /test code you'll use those helper methods as well.

If your helper code leans more towards testing, then it should be generic enough not to depend on the code in /src. That way, you can swap out one /src for another and test it out using the same /test helper methods. Essentially, it's like having a lightweight test "framework" that you can use anywhere in your codebase.

I've done something similar in C# on a small scale that uses inheritance and [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), specifically related to unit testing with [NUnit](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=home).